# How to get actualHeight of a UserControl on a for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, height

I have a foreach loop that add UserControl into a stackPanel.

The problem is that I need the height of the UserControl, because it's not the same for all userControl.

Note: I have to add the userControl on the grid after having his Height.

Here is what I tried :

```
            foreach(Verset verset in sourate.versets)
        {
            Paper_Usercontrol.UC_Paper_Vers uc_verset = new Paper_Usercontrol.UC_Paper_Vers(verset);

            uc_verset.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            uc_verset.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), uc_verset.DesiredSize));
            uc_verset.UpdateLayout();

            totalSize += Convert.ToInt32(uc_verset.ActualHeight);
            // ... }
```

That give code give the value on ActualHeight of "99.85". I don't have any idea of what that value can be, it can't be the real one because it is the same value everytime, but when it show the userControl they have different size.

The other I tested is to add the UserControl on a temporary grid before having his height :

```
            foreach(Verset verset in sourate.versets)
        {
            Paper_Usercontrol.UC_Paper_Vers uc_verset = new Paper_Usercontrol.UC_Paper_Vers(verset);
            Grid_InitElement.Children.Add(uc_verset);

            uc_verset.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            uc_verset.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), uc_verset.DesiredSize));
            uc_verset.UpdateLayout();

            totalSize += Convert.ToInt32(uc_verset.ActualHeight);

            Grid_InitElement.Children.Clear();

            // ... }
```

This code give me the Height of 705; it is the height of the Grid_InitElement, again don't ask me why I don't know why it do that

Here is an image if I let all the userControl on the temporaryGrid (to show u they have different size) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnEO4.png)

Here is my userControl WPF :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Zone_Muslim.Paper_Usercontrol.UC_Paper_Vers"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Zone_Muslim.Paper_Usercontrol"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          >
    
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ar" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0">

        </TextBlock>
        <Separator Height="10" Width="0"></Separator>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ph" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="10,0,10,0">
        </TextBlock>
        <Separator Height="10" Width="0"></Separator>
        <TextBlock x:Name="fr" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <Separator Height="20" Width="0"></Separator>

    </StackPanel>
```

ps: the Text of the TextBlock is set on the Initialization of the UserControl, and it's that text that determine the size of the UserControl :

```
        public UC_Paper_Vers(Verset verset)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ar.Text = verset.text_arabe;
        ph.Text = verset.text_phonetique;
        fr.Text = verset.position_ds_sourate + ". " + verset.text;
    }
```

Please help me find a solution to have the actualHeight of my userControl

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand, could you tell me what to do?

Comment: In the second attempt, you get the Grid Height because all child elements are added to the same Grid cell, i.e. Column 0 and Row 0. Due to their Horizontal- and VertivalAlignment, all child elements will fill the entire Grid.

Comment: @dzaeOK Have you tried calling Measure with a "real" size instead of infinity?

Comment: I delete everytime the UIElement after having his Height, and even with a stackPanel it didnt work :/

Comment: No, I took this code from this site

Comment: The Width will still be the same, only the height change. @Clemens I updated my post and an image and changing to InvalidateVisual make the height to "99.85" :/

Comment: Changing it to noWrap dont change anything :/

Comment: You are doing the Arrange with DesiredSize. That will not deliver the desired result, because it does not enforce text wrapping in the UserControls. You should instead first determine the final width of the controls, and do their Measure and Arrange with that value.

Comment: It don't work sorry

Comment: It does for me with Measure, Arrange and UpdateLayout with a fixed pre-defined width passed to both Measure and Arrange.

Comment: Why aren't you using an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate to populate, what essentially is a list on screen?